Access Point using NetworkManager only allows 6 devices to connect
I've a Raspberry Pi running Debian 12 (bookworm) and have set up an access point with the following command:
sudo nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 mode ap con-name MY_AP ssid MySSID \
   connection.autoconnect yes \
   ipv4.method shared \
   ipv4.addresses 192.168.5.1/24 \
   802-11-wireless.band bg \
   802-11-wireless.channel 7 \
   ipv6.method disabled \
   wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk \
   wifi-sec.psk 'PASSWORD

This works fine, but it looks like it's only allowing 6 devices to connect. If I try and connect a 7th, it says it won't connect and nothing appears in the NetworkManager logs to indicate that there was an attempted connection or why the connection wasn't permitted.
I've tried connecting different devices in different orders, starting and restarting NetworkManager and playing with config files, but it always stops playing ball after 6 devices have connected.
If I look in the NetworkManager logs, I see things like the following:
May 15 12:13:22 farmpi dnsmasq-dhcp[66325]: DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.5.104 98:f4:ab:e0:b2:26 strip2-4646
May 15 12:13:22 farmpi dnsmasq-dhcp[66325]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.5.104 98:f4:ab:e0:b2:26
May 15 12:13:22 farmpi dnsmasq-dhcp[66325]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.5.104 98:f4:ab:e0:b2:26
May 15 12:13:22 farmpi dnsmasq-dhcp[66325]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) 98:f4:ab:e0:b2:26
May 15 12:13:16 farmpi dnsmasq[66325]: cleared cache
May 15 12:13:16 farmpi dnsmasq[66325]: using nameserver 192.168.55.1#53
May 15 12:13:16 farmpi dnsmasq[66325]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
May 15 12:13:16 farmpi dnsmasq-dhcp[66325]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.5.10 -- 192.168.5.254, lease time 1h
May 15 12:13:16 farmpi dnsmasq[66325]: chown of PID file /run/nm-dnsmasq-wlan0.pid failed: Operation not permitted

This seems ok to me (chown error aside, but I assume that's not relevant?). The DHCP IP range should allow more then 244 devices to connect, and the connections are being handled correctly, it's just for some unfathomable reason, it stops doing that after the 6th device.
I increased the log level to TRACE to see if I could get any more information, but nothing is printed about devices trying to connect.
Any advice on how to try and debug this would be greatly appreciated.

What is the subnet coming from your ISP? I'm going to guess that it's 255.255.255.248/29 leaving you a pool of 7 addresses minus 1 addresses (192.168.5.7 for the broadcast address) leaving your DHCP server a total of 6 Addresses to hand out. I'll post a screenshot in an answer below if you like with an explanation.

Thanks @eyoung100 That sounds really interesting but is pushing the limits of my networking knowledge. How would I find that out? The interface that connects to our router is wlan1 and the only thing in the logs that looks relevant is the following:
May 15 12:13:11 farmpi NetworkManager[66135]: <info>  [1715771591.3254] dhcp4 (wlan1): state changed new lease, address=192.168.55.115

If I look at the output of ip a for two interfaces I get:
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000     inet 192.168.5.1/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0 4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000     inet 192.168.55.115/24 brd 192.168.55.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan1

Can you provide the model of the modem that came from your ISP, as this explanation requires an answer instead of multiple REALLY LONG comments, as I'm assuming you'd like to extend your knowledge.  Don't worry I knew this was coming....  I won't expose your IP or anything, I'm just going to use screenshots of your setup page in your modem/router combo etc to explain what's going on
